# How do I remove extra spaces from powershell output?

Tags: apache, powershell, ssh

I am using Powershell to ssh into my Linux server and tailing my apache log files.

ssh user@domain.tld -p800 -i ..ssh\id_rsa_test tail /var/log/httpd/access_log -fn0 > test.log

When tailing the text looks fine, When opening the file I piped the text into it looks fine.

The application I am piping the output to fails. When I tail the file I am piping into I see every single character separated by a space.

using out-file with no parameters does the same thing. When I cut and paste the contents of the file in notepad to another notepad file, the other application can read it. How can I fix this?

Here's a sample of what I am referring to:

> d o m a i n . c o m   7 2 . 2 2 4 . 2 4 9 . 1 7   -   -   [ 1 0 / D e
>   c / 2 0 1 3 : 0 7 : 5 0 : 5 6   - 0 6  0 0 ]   " G E T   / v a n e / v
>   i e w f o r u m . p h p ? f = 1 & s i d = 3 b 4 3 b d 9 9 9 a 7 d b 2
>   0 c 6 6 9 7 5 b 2  3 8 2 4 a 9 6 1 9   H T T P / 1 . 1 "   2 0 0   9 3
>   7 6   " h t t p : / / w w w . d o m a i n  . c o m / j a  n e / v i e
>   w t o p i c . p h p ? f = 1 & t = 8 0 2 3 & p = 3 4 3 4 5 0 & s i d =
>   3 b 4 3 b d 9 9 9 a 7 d b 2 0 c 6 6 9  7 5 b 2 3 8 2 4 a 9 6 1 9 "   "
>   M o z i l l a / 4 . 0   ( c o m p a t i b l e ;   M S I E   8 . 0 ;
>   W i n d o w s   N  T   6 . 0 ;   W O W 6 4 ;   T r i d e n t / 4 . 0 ;
>   G T B 7 . 5 ;   S L C C 1 ;   . N E T   C L R   2 . 0 . 5 0 7 2 7  ;
>   M e d i a   C e n t e r   P C   5 . 0 ;   . N E T   C L R   3 . 5 . 2
>   1 0 2 2 ;   . N E T   C L R   3 . 5 . 3 0 7 2  9 ;   M D D C ;   . N E
>   T   C L R   3 . 0 . 3 0 7 2 9 ;   . N E T 4 . 0 C ;   B R I / 1 ;   B
>   R I / 2 ) "  d o m a i n . c o m   5 . 9 . 1 0 6 . 2 4 1   -   -   [ 1
>   0 / D e c / 2 0 1 3 : 0 7 : 5 0 : 5 8   - 0 6 0 0 ]   "  G E T   / r o
>   b o t s . t x t   H T T P / 1 . 0 "   2 0 0   -   " - "   " M o z i l
>   l a / 5 . 0   ( c o m p a t i b l e  ;   M J 1 2 b o t / v 1 . 4 . 4 ;
>   h t t p : / / w w w . m a j e s t i c 1 2 . c o . u k / b o t . p h p
>   ? + ) "

Comment: Can you show the code where you pipe into powerShell?

Comment: Unicode, may I introduce Damiel? That is, Powershell's output is Unicode per default, and what you see are dual byte characters.

Comment: the command above starting with ssh is within powershell. I open Powershell, then ssh into the Linux server and pipe the output into the third party app or direct it into a file. 

I am using msysgit for ssh.

Comment: How are you piping the output?  Out-File will format the output as Unicode, but you can set the -Encoding parameter for ASCII.  Add-Content and Set-Content will write to the file without doing any re-formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pipe our output though out-file, set-conent, or add-content you can use the -Encoding parameter to force it to ASCII:

```
ssh user@domain.tld -p800 -i ..ssh\id_rsa_test tail /var/log/httpd/access_log -fn0 | Add-Content  test.log -encoding ASCII

ssh user@domain.tld -p800 -i ..ssh\id_rsa_test tail /var/log/httpd/access_log -fn0 | Set-Content  test.log -encoding ASCII

ssh user@domain.tld -p800 -i ..ssh\id_rsa_test tail /var/log/httpd/access_log -fn0 | Out-File  test.log -encoding ASCII
```

Comment: This works for saving to the file and is also wonderful. I used out-file -encoding ASCII for that. But I still need to pipe the output to another app in real time. How can I change from unicode to ASCII in a pipe?

Comment: Try: app1 | out-string | app2

Comment: Tried that last night, but out-file demands to save to a file.

Comment: Not out-file, out-string.

Comment: What it's doing now is just hanging as though SSH never releases control to the next app.

Comment: Not sure how do debug that if it has to be a direct pipe.  Can the SSH ouput live in a varialbe temporarily?

Comment: Yes, I have been using it with out-file -encoding ASCII and it saves correctly. I have narrowed it down to logstalgia just plain refusing to execute and hanging. Seems like an old bug that's recurred with the introduction of PSv3. I haven't confirmed this yet.